# SignalR being blocked?

Tags: https, signalr

When starting up a C# SignalR client on a certain machine, the connection will not connect and Fiddler tells me this is the response to the SSLV3 handshake:

*System.IO.IOException Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.*

I can make a simple WebRequest in LinqPad to the root URL listening on Nancy, and that works fine.  My Client also works on many other machines in other networks (The Hub is on AWS).  How can I tell whether the SignalR Hub the source of the issue, or the client,  or something in between?